# IdentityServer4: allow login only for specific user/client combinations

Tags: identityserver4

I want to use IdentityServer4 as a common login for my own web applications.

Not all users are free to use all apps and obviously I could make all apps have users be rejected that aren't allowed to access them.

It seems a little more elegant to have a common "this app isn't activated for you" page centralized in the identity server though. That way, I need to implement that page only once. The identity server would have to have knowledge about which user may access which client, but that's reasonable in my scenario: they are all my own apps anyway.

I'm not sure what the right place is to hook the test in. It can't be the login page as the user may already be logged in to the identity server from a client he does have access to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't go for this approach, but I do not know the design of your apps.

I think that the url may confuse the user. Since it is the url of the IdentityServer where they see the *"this app isn't activated for you"* message. What does that mean to the user and where to go from there?

Besides, IdentityServer is meant to authenticate users, not to authorize users. So it doesn't seem right to move this kind of logic to IdentityServer. It also sounds like extra work.

Keep it simple. Keep authorization close to the resource and create one page with the message. Copy that to all your apps and css does the rest.

And use the default behaviour. In case an anonymous user hits a secured method, the user will automatically be rerouted to the login page. In case an authenticated user hits a method where it doesn't have access, it reroutes to the default (apps) Account/Denied page.

You can override the path in you startup configuration:

```
.AddCookie("Cookies", options =>
{
    options.AccessDeniedPath = "/accountdenied";
})
```

You can show the *"this app isn't activated for you"* page, or you can go from there and redirect with code to the IdentityServer page. With the possibility to add additional information to customize the page.

Perhaps you can enter the page of IdentityServer instead, if that fits your design better. I haven't tried it, so I do not know if that's possible.

But in any case I would keep the authorization logic in the app.

Comment: That seems good advice and I'm unsure at this point. I was thinking to have it centralized as maybe I will have more of the user management (which app is active for which user/account and what permissions they have) more centralized as well. In my scenario it seems reasonable not to have all apps have their own user/account-related UI. I think I will still go with your suggestion of simply showing an app-specific access-denied-page - I didn't consider that I need such a page for each app anyway.